# Excel encontrando um "problema de conteúdo" na tabela após executar Openpyxl

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, openpyxl

Basicamente, estou executando um Openpyxl nessa planilha, porém, quando abro ela após a execução do código (até pq o terminal não da erro algum), o Excel me diz que encontrou um problema de conteúdo na planilha e pergunta se a desejo recuperar.

O código consiste em executar um ProcV na E3 e se eu executo esse ProcV diretamente na planilha, ele funciona. Mas por algum motivo o Openpyxl está bugando a planilha; talvez o problema seja pq o procv ali ta buscando uma pasta do PC e o OpenPyxl não reconhece dessa forma?! Não sei...

Alguém sabe o que possa ser?

O código:

```
planilha = load_workbook("base.xlsx")

data = planilha.active

data["E3"] = "=PROCV(A3;'C:\\Users\\eu\\Desktop\\main\\[lg.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$I;8;FALSO)"
     
planilha.save("base.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação do OpenPyXL](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-formulae) você deve usar o nome em inglês das fórmulas, então em vez de `PROCV` você deve usar `VLOOKUP`

Além do nome a documentação também diz para usar vírgula para separar os parâmetros em vez de ponto e vírgula